# Display images relative on another resized image

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a quiz editor.
User should be able to put check box on image

I have a div who represent a zone
inside, there is an image
on the image there are check box.

image may have any size, i don't know the size of image
check box should be positioned relative to the image
image should be center on the zone

I need something dynamic, screen should be resizable

i have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="boundary" >
  <div class="mycomponent">
    <div class ="container"> 
      <img style="display: block; max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="image.jpg" >
      <img style="left: 20.3501%; top: 44.448%; display: block; position: absolute;" id="imgi0" src="uncheck.png">
      <img style="left: 52.7185%; top: 35.7171%; position: absolute;" id="imgi1" src="uncheck.png">
      <img style="left: 82.0456%; top: 31.3517%; position: absolute;" id="imgi2" src="uncheck.png"> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.boundary
{
    left: 0px;
    display: block;  
    position: absolute;  
    right: 0px;  
    bottom: 50px;  
    top: 75px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
.mycomponent
{
    height: 43%; 
    width: 89.29%; 
    top: 26.78%; 
    left: 5.496%; 
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    position: absolute; 
    padding: 0px; 
    text-align: center; 
    border-color:#000000;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: beige;
}

.container
{
   display: inline-block;  
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jlogan/91p06yjm/

This code works fine on chrome and safari but failed in firefox and ie9+

any clue ?

Thansk a lot

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes in Chrome, there are just three gray little squares on the picture. SO first, if you need checkboxes, use `<input type='checkbox'>` and not an `<img>`

Comment: The little grey square are the checkbox. I removed all js for clarity of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I updated and cleared your fiddle to make it clearer. You can give your class "mycomponent" `max-height` instead of `height`.

```
.container{
    max-height: 43%; // You had "height:43%";
    width: 89.29%; 
    top: 26.78%; 
    left: 5.496%; 
    overflow-y: hidden; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    position: absolute; 
    padding: 0px; 
    text-align: center; 
    border-color:#000000;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

Working **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjbrfaoq/2/)**

It's working for me in every browser, even if you resize the window.

Comment: The checkboxes move on the image while resizing : http://postimg.org/image/91nnce3in/

Comment: Thanks, the image display well, but the checkbox are not relatives to the image.

i need to display the checkbox relative to the image.

i also tried to define display: initial and position: initial to the container. the image render well too, but unfortunately not the checkbox

Comment: @Serge Okay, I'll try fix that :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it still doesn't works.

I have is 2 issues :
image is not displayed well. it can be solved by define container display inline instead of inline-block and remove position.
in that case image is displayed well.

but second issue the check box left are relative to the container. i need relative to the image.

Comment: What do you mean by "not displayed well"? What should it look like?

Comment: image should be displayed full (means all the image but smaller than original size)
the check box should be "lock" on each foreground tree and the third on the guy in middle

Comment: The image should fill the whole container? The checkbox positioning is easy to do. Use Firebug for example (F12 in your browser) and then you can easily change the number of % in css.